# Splitting path into equal parts

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, math

I have a path that is made up of a list of points (x,y) and have a length of L. I would like to break the path up into equal parts of E = L/# of parts. There is a diagram people to show the problem.

[image]

Comment: What's holding you back?

Comment: I assume you mean length, not distance ?

Comment: "E = greatest common divisor of lengths of the segments" should be the answer here; if I didn't misjudge the question.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the cumulated segment lengths `(0, Dab, Dab+Dbc, Dab+Dbc+Dcd... D)`. Your split points are equally spaced, at (curvilinear) abscissas `i.D/N`. Using a simple loop, you will find to which segment every split point belongs. Let point `i` be in segment `k` of length `Dk` and cumulated length `Lk`: the split point is located at the fraction `(i.D/n-Lk)/Dk` of this segment.